# Overriding the paragraph style in the LNCS document class

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, document-classes, lncs

I am using the [LNCS document class](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) to typeset a paper. I would like to keep most of this document style, but I do not like how paragraphs are typeset. The heading of the paragraph is in italics, which is not enough contrast to the rest of the text. I would like to change this to bold text.

How can I override the paragraph style, being minimally invasive?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of your paragraph usage that displays the current, unwanted behaviour? It avoids having to re-invent the wheel to get at the point you're at.

Comment: Are you planning on submitting your document to LNCS? If you are, it's best not to modify their style.

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd{\paragraph}{\itshape}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}` should be sufficient. But I have a couple of doubts: (1) if you're using the class for submitting to Springer, don't modify the style; (2) `\paragraph` is the fourth level of sectioning: are you sure you want to use it and give it much prominence? Moreover, you'd get the same as `\subsubsection`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Not submitting to Springer and the LNCS style is not required, so patching is okay.

Comment: @egreg I want the text to start in the same line as the heading. I need only three levels of sectioning. If it is possible to do this with `\subsubsection`, that would be fine also.

Comment: @clstaudt `\subsubsection` already does that.

Comment: @egreg Oh, then my question does not really make sense any more. Still, I've learned how to patch commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing what you ask is very easy: add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\paragraph}{\itshape}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
```

to your document preamble.

However, this will make the typesetting of `\paragraph` titles very similar to what's already done for `\subsubsection`.

As far as I understand, the `llncs` class has three levels of sectioning, corresponding to `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. The last one is unnumbered by default.

The example document uses `\paragraph` for comments about proofs or similar things, so just as a “special paragraph” of text. I believe this is good usage, but I wouldn't give these special paragraphs much prominence than they already are given with the title in italics.

Trust me: a paragraph starting with a title in italics and preceded by some vertical space *is* noticeable. Rather, it's more questionable that there is no vertical space at the end of this special paragraph.

You can define a `comments` environment that remedies to this situation:

```
\newenvironment{comments}[1]
  {\paragraph{#1}}
  {\par\addvspace{12pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}}
```

that will add the same vertical space at the bottom as it adds at the top.

Don't abuse `\subsubsection` for this purpose.